# How to calculate running balance

Tags: sql

```
SELECT              
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME,101) AS   GLTR_PSTNG_DATE,
    GLTR_DOC_CODE, GLTR_OUR_DOC_NO,     
    CONVERT (VARCHAR,GLTR_DOC_DATETIME,101) AS   GLTR_DOC_DATETIME,
    GLTR_TRAN_AMT, GLTR_FC_CODE,            
    GLTR_FC_AMT          
FROM            
    GLAS_GL_TRANSACTIONS            
WHERE            
    GLTR_COMP_CODE = '1' 
    AND GLTR_ACCT_CODE = SUBSTRING('1110011',4,4)            
    AND GLTR_PSTNG_DATETIME  BETWEEN '05/13/2008' AND '11/26/2009'          
    AND ISNULL('bv',GLTR_DOC_CODE) = GLTR_DOC_CODE
GROUP BY
    GLTR_PSTNG_DATEtime
```

This query is fetching from the database to the grid here my scenario is when the transamt retrieves it should calculate the running balance amount and it should be displayed.

It should show like this (running balance is not a database field item)

```
gltr_tran_amt  running balance
-480.000        -480.000
 480.000         0
-2540.500       -2540.500
 2540.500        0
-3800.000       -3800.00
 3800.000        0
 500             500
 1000            1500
```

it should retrieve and show like this

Comment: Voting to close. I do not understand your question and I can't imagine you've put even a little effort in this question. Using a spell checker, capitalizing "I" & the beginnings of sentences and avoid slang words like "pls" is the least you should do. Adding some more information like the layout of your database would be helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, as the comment stated, you should state you your question a little better. Also, providing a schema would have helped a lot more.

I think I know what you want to do, and this should help you into the correct direction

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        DateVal DATETIME,
        Amount FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '01 Jan 2009', -480
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '01 Jan 2009', 480
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '02 Jan 2009', -2540.500
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '02 Jan 2009', 2540.500
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '02 Jan 2009', -3800.000
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '03 Jan 2009', 3800.000
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '04 Jan 2009', 500
INSERT INTO @Table (DateVal,Amount) SELECT '05 Jan 2009', 1000

SELECT  * ,
        (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @Table WHERE ID <= t.ID) RunningTotal
FROM    @Table t
```

Comment: Gaaah why use float and not decimal for the Amount??